# Why is this Daemon thread blocking?

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess, python-multithreading

Why does the following code block on cc.start()? The crawler.py contains code similar to http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-from-script

```
import scrapy
import threading
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def worker():
    crawler = Popen('python crawler.py', stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
    while True:
        line = crawler.stderr.readline()
        print(line.strip())

cc = threading.Thread(target=worker())
cc.setDaemon(True)
cc.start()
print "Here" # This is not printed
# Do more stuff
```

crawler.py contains the following code:

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'stackoverflow'
    start_urls = ['http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes']

def parse(self, response):
    for href in response.css('.question-summary h3 a::attr(href)'):
        full_url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
        yield scrapy.Request(full_url, callback=self.parse_question)

    process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
    })

process.crawl(MySpider)
process.start() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
```

Comment: The code itself will break because you're not using `subprocess.Popen` for instance.

Comment: Sorry I added the import statement later, I fixed it. That is not the issue.

Comment: Then i suggest you update your code accordingly to weed out any possible causes.

Comment: Also, you'd might want to explain why you're running a python script via `Popen(...)` because that rarely makes any sense at all. You could just as easily wrap that in a `import crawler`.

Comment: I added the contents of the script being called. I am using Popen because I want to run the crawler as part of my project and then do a lot more stuff after that (capturing packets for one thing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

threading.Thread takes callable object as argument (ex function name), you are actually calling the function when you are creating a thread instance

```
cc = threading.Thread(target=worker())
```

what you need to do is just pass the function to be called with thread

```
cc = threading.Thread(target=worker)
```